# Loop regex until only :okthisisanemoji: exists between sets of :

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, discord, discord.js

I am using regex to change my translation bot sending custom emojis. By doing this I can remove unsupported unlatin names and whitespaces:

`data.text.replace(/:.*?:/, ":okthisisanemoji:");`
This works fine and the translator does send custom emojis now but I want it to loop until the only thing that is inbetween any : is :okthisisanemoji: .

Right now I cant do more than one ethically because a normal loop would just replace :okthisisanemoji: forever.

Can someone help describe to me how to create a loop which replaces the string of < : translatedemojiname : emojiID> to <:okthisisanemoji:emojiID> but for every emoji sent in the message instead of only the last or first 3-4.

Code is this:

```
   if (data.author)
   {
      if (data.text.includes("<:")) 
// -> data.text = <: gelb:590653333124022288>
      {
         data.text = data.text.replace(/:.*?:/, ":okthisisanemoji:"); 
// -> <:okthisisanemoji:590653333124022288>     ( but right now it does not do it for everything.
         data.text = data.text.replace(": ", ":"); // -> "ABCDEFGHSTUVWXYZ"
         data.text = data.text.replace("<: ", "<:");
      }
   }
```

[image: Discord]

The source code is here: https://github.com/Zyc0r3/RitaBot/tree/emoji

And the file is https://github.com/ZyC0R3/RitaBot/blob/emoji/src/core/send.js

It's a translation bot for Discord and right now the custom emoji is a problem. Please help

Website is here: https://ritabot.org

Discord Server is here: https://discord.gg/NAxA3nf

Comment: Do you mean you want to find any text between `:` except `okthisisanemoji`? Try `/:(?!okthisisanemoji:).*?:/`

Comment: I want to replace the data.text string from the translated emoji name and whitespaces to
<:okthisisanemoji:emojiIDdisplayed>            I can do one emoji at a time right now per message but it cant do many at once.

I need it to do every string between : : at once.   Like .replaceAll in Java to replace :translatedname :  with :okthisisanemoji:

Answer (score 2):

Using regex

```
<(:\s*[a-z]+:\s*)([0-9]+)>
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/07mRib/1)**

```js
const text = `<:Gelb: 590653333124022288><:Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288><: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <okthisisanemoji:5906533331 24022288><:Gelb:
590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb:
590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb: 590653333124022288> <: Gelb:
590653333124022288>
<:Gelb: 590653333124022288>
<:Rot: 590653332616511496>`

const regx = /<:\s*[a-z]+\s*:\s*([0-9]+)>/mgi

console.log(text.replace(regx, '<:okthisisanemoji:$1>'))
```

Comment: The way that the translator whitespaces is throwing it off.    It is only doing the :okthisisanemoji: for some of them.

`<: Gelb: 590653333124022288>`       
`

Do you know if I can strip all whitespaces between < and > so that the problem doesnt occur and the whitespace doesnt mess it up?

Comment: What I'd need is regex replacing all whitespaces with "" between < and > and then running the regex above it should work

Comment: It is doing this right now
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/755900727028744232/763224374509043722/yQzudbdX9aEQSAABAAAkAACPRDYFDbTP1wgSIgAASAABAAAkAACFAJDLR4JurYIA0EgAAQAAJAAAgAgQ9FAGymD0US9AABIAAEgA.png

Comment: @Artanis Check updated. next time post text instead of an image. OCRs are not perfect. Keep in mind, that you are seeking help.

Comment: @User63   Yeah sorry,   my mistake.   Thank you so much!